# How do I make it so when an item with a tag is thrown on the ground, mobs close to it (1 block) burn?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making some items to use for setting mobs on fire, cuz one of my custom mobs is weak to fire and this is one I came up with but I'm having some trouble (mostly with the fire part). So, how do I make it so when an item with a tag is thrown on the ground, mobs close to it (1 block) burn?

Answer (score 2):

```
execute as @e[type=item,nbt={Item:{id:"minecraft:blaze_rod",tag:{nbt:{Tags:["all_shall_burn"]}}}}] at @s run execute as @e[distance=0.1..1] run data merge entity @s {Fire:10s}
```

Will check for any blaze_rod with the tag `{Tags:["all_shall_burn"]}` and set entities around them on fire for 10 seconds (would not affect players as minecraft does not allow you to modify player nbt without using mods)

Comment: I would remove the check for `all_shall_burn` to the target selector and remove it from the nbt check. Checking nbt is always less efficient.